# Should do vs should have to do

Tags: modal-verbs

Do they both have the same meaning?

1. You should do that.
2. You should have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

- "Should do": it would be reasonable if the subject does something.
- "Should have to do" it would be reasonable if the subject were
  required to do something.

> You should do that.

The person speaking is suggesting the receiver to do something. It's normally used to give advice/suggestion. The nature of the action suggested is optional, i.e. it is not required that the subject does what is suggested but it would be nice if they do.

> For example: "You should know how to give CPR."

It would be nice if the subject knows how to give CPR because it might be useful one day.

> You should have to do that.

In this context, "should have to" means "should be **required** to", i.e. it would be reasonable if the receiver were required to do something.

> For example: "Coaches should have to know how to give CPR."
>   The speaker is suggesting that coaches should be required to be capable of giving CPR (because it could be vital in their work).